# Polymer Core-Ajax File upload

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

i want to upload a file from a form with core-ajax.
Right now it my code looks like this:

```
<core-ajax 
  auto="false"
  method="POST"
  url="/file-upload" 
  handleAs="json"
  on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"
  contentType="multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7da24f2e50046"
  params="{{item}}"
  id="ajax"></core-ajax>

<form>
 <input type="text" name="Name" id="name"></br>
 <label class="formLine">File</label></br>
 <input type="file" name="File" id="file"></br>
 <paper-button raisedbutton="" label="send" role="button" aria-label="disabled" class="formLine" on-tap="{{click}}"></paper-button>
</form>
```

with the following javascript-code:

```
click: function(){
var name = this.$.name;
var File = this.$.file;

this.item = {
  'Name': name.value,
  'File':File.value
  };
this.$.ajax.go();
}
```

So when i send the request there is no data to process.
In the previous version i handled this with a regular form and used multiparty to parse the request.

How should i send and handle the data?

Answer (score 11):

core-ajax doesn't make file upload that easy. It provides a few defaults that are geared more towards simpler requests with key/val params.

There's a couple of different ways to [send file/blob data using XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-sending). `core-ajax` sets a default `contentType` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ([code](https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/blob/master/core-ajax.html#L167)). Instead, you want to override that and allow the browser to set its own `content-type` to create a mime multipart requrst. Here, I'm using `FormData()` to do that:

```
<input type="file" name="File" id="file" on-change="{{setFiles}}">

<core-ajax id="ajax" url="/file-upload" method="POST"
           handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>

...

setFiles: function(e, detail, sender) {
  var formData = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0, f; f = sender.files[i]; ++i) {
    formData.append(sender.name, f,
                    this.$.name.value || f.name);
  }

  this.$.ajax.body = formData;
  // Override default type set by core-ajax.
  // Allow browser to set the mime multipart content type itself. 
  this.$.ajax.contentType = null;
},
upload: function(e, detail, sender) {
  if (!this.$.file.files.length) {
    alert('Please include a file');
    return;
  }
  this.$.ajax.go();
},
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/himetoco/1/edit

Comment: Hello @ebidel, the request payload ends up to be [object Object]. And content type is "text/plain;charset=UTF-8". Actually, even XMLHttpRequest using FormData behaves the same in a polymer app.

Comment: here are two different requests from a Windows 7 machine with Chrome 36, runs successfully (http://i.imgur.com/Awcczzy.png) and a Linux machine with Chromium 31, fails (http://i.imgur.com/xzLV2fp.png)

Comment: I can confirm that switching to Chrome 37 on Linux machine solved this.

Comment: Simplest and most complete solution: use a [`<file-input>` element](https://github.com/garstasio/file-input) inside of an [`ajax-form`](https://github.com/garstasio/ajax-form).  Disclaimer, I'm the author of both elements.

Comment: Perfect solution. A big thumbs up... :) Cheers
Even it works perfectly for iron ajax of Polymer 1