# Polymer core-ajax file upload progress

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

how do I add a progress bar. I use the code provided by eric bidelman here => [Polymer Core-Ajax File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25099938/polymer-core-ajax-file-upload)

```
downloadinit: function( event, detail, sender ){
            this.files = sender.files;
            for ( var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ) {
                var file = this.files[i]
                this.uploadsize += file.size;
                this.fileList[this.uploadPop] = file.name;
                this.uploadPop += 1;
            }

            event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
            event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

            for( var i = 0, f; f = this.files[i]; ++i) {
                this.data.append( sender.name, f, f.name );
            }
            this.queryUrl2 = "projects/submit.php?pjid="+this.projDetails.projectid;
            this.submitBody = this.data;
            this.$.ajaxAction2.contentType = null;
        },
        triggerDownload: function(){
            this.$.ajaxAction2.go();
            data = new FormData;
            this.files = null;
            this.fileList = [];
            this.submitBody = null;
            this.uploadsize = 0;
            this.uploadPop = 0;
        },
```

Comment: core-ajax doesn't provide the necessary hooks for this. You need to be able to attach event listeners to the raw xhr object, which core-ajax doesn't expose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress. Can you file a feature request?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I'll try to file a request. I'm pretty sure a lot of people may need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'loading' mask.

```
<template>
<form>
   <paper-input type="File" label="Choose File" ... ></paper-input>
   <paper-button label="Send" on-click="{{sendData}}" raisedButton></paper-button>
</form>
<core-ajax id="ajax" url="/upload"
           method="POST"
           on-core-response="{{onResponse}}"
           ....
></core-ajax>
</template>
<script>
sendData: function () {
    ...
    this.$.ajax.go();
    this.spiningLoadingMask(true);
    ...
},

onResponse: function () {
    ...
    this.spiningLoadinMask(false);
    ...
},

spiningLoadingMask: function (val) {
    if(val){
    ... //start moving the wheel
    } else {
    ... //stop that wheel
    }
}
</script>
```

something like that can work, there is not a 'Progress Bar' but a spining wheel is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request implementing the missing feature https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/pull/27